# Problem with each()

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('ul.course-nav li a').each(function() {
  alert(5);
  if ('#' == $(this).attr('href')) {
   $(this).addClass('lessOpacity');
  }
 });

});    //-->
</script>
```

HTML of course contains searched elements:

```
  <ul class="course-nav">
   <li><a href="navigator.php?kam=zakladnyNahladKurzu&amp;id=1&amp;pos=2" class="next"><img src="css/images/16_arrow_right.png" alt="next"></a></li>

   <li><a href="#" class="prev"><img src="css/images/16_arrow_left.png" alt="prev"></a></li>
   <li><a href="navigator.php?kam=zakladnyNahladKurzu&amp;id=1" class="start"><img src="css/images/16_arrow_first.png" alt="start"></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Yet it doesn't work. Not even alerts pop up. Any suggestions?

Comment: When are you running the jQuery function? Is it wrapped in a ready() event?

Comment: @Pekka Yes it is. Everything is wrapped in $(document).ready(function() { }.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `each` there, you can simply do:

```
$('ul.course-nav a[href="#"]').addClass('lessOpacity');
```

The jQuery's implicit iteration will look through all links whose `href` is set to `#` and add the class accordingly. Make sure to wrap your code in ready handler:

```
$(function(){
  $('ul.course-nav a[href="#"]').addClass('lessOpacity');
});
```

Comment: @Manie look at the code. He only adds the class if the href is #

Answer (score 1):

intead of

```
  $('ul.course-nav a').each(function() {
    alert(5);
    if ('#' == $(this).attr('href')) {
    $(this).addClass('lessOpacity');
   }
 });
```

replace with

```
 $('ul.course-nav li a').each(function() {
    alert(5);
    if ('#' == $(this).attr('href')) {
    $(this).addClass('lessOpacity');
   }
 });
```

Comment: Not necessary, 'cause the space is the descendant selector not the child selector.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your function with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // here goes your function
});
```

The whole page has to be loaded until jQuery can modify anything!

Comment: dont forget to close this with ");" at the end ;D

Comment: It is wrapped, I just shortened the code to make the question clear.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another $(document).ready() function on the page is executed instead of the presented one.